# OpenGL.org down, any mirror sites for libraries and include downloads?

Tags: opengl

http://opengl.org/ and http://www.khronos.org/ seems to be currently unavailable. Is there any good alternative mirror sites?

I am looking for OpenGL 4.4 Libraries and Includes download for VC.

Comment: I'm still looking for the API reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, usually you want to use glew or a similiar library in order to get the OpenGL functions. You can grab a copy of glew here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/. The libraries should come bundled with VC so you simply add OpenGL32.lib to your linker's additional dependencies.

Comment: I can't find the GL includes and libraries in the glew-packages, am I downloading the wrong archive from http://glew.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Well, usually you simply include glew.h which should be in glew's include folder. In that header all OpenGL functions are defined

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! So the #include <GL/glut.h> and link to OpenGL32.lib isn't needed then, only #include <GL/glew.h> and link to glew32.lib? I thought glew only extended the library, not replaced it.

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated. You will need to link to OpenGL32.lib as well as to glew32(s).lib. You must not include <GL/glut.h> but <GL/glew.h> instead. Also you must not include any other OpenGL header before first including <GL/glew.h>. Another thing is that if you're linking to glew32s.lib you will have to define GLEW_STATIC or you'll get the weirdest errors.

Comment: Okay, I tried your suggestion but it fails. I believe it is because I have OpenGL32.lib for OpenGL 1.1. I need a mirror download site for the 4.x - files since OpenGL.org is down, that is what my question is about really. Glew take me a bit longer towards my goal, but it does not solve my issue not having the OpenGL files

Comment: ... There is no extra library for OpenGL 4.x. You always use OpenGL32.lib on windows. The functions you want are loaded at runtime. Every single function is loaded by a function loading utility which is glew in our case. There simply is no library containing all functions for the reason of extensions. Can you tell me what exactly fails?

Comment: Ah okay sorry, I am new to all this, and doing the mistake starting out with a really really old tutorial on OpenGL just give me headache now when trying to implement Shaders, when everything I have learned was depricated stuff. I thought the OpenGL32.lib actually changed for every new version of OpenGL, so I needed a new one. It was actually something totally irrelevant that failed, I used an incorrect argument to the `glShaderSource()` function. Well, I guess I need to take some time actually trying to do this correct, hopefully I will "get it" anytime soon. Thanks for your patience with me!

Comment: No problem, never mind. And if you've got any further questions, don't shy to ask them, ok?

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL is not a library, it's an API specification. What you can download at http://opengl.org are just the specification documents and reference C include headers. But there are no library downloads there because, well, OpenGL is not a library.

The actual OpenGL implementation ships as part of your GPU's driver. That's also what ultimately determines which version of OpenGL you can use: The GPU on the system the program is executed on. The major OpenGL version designates the hardware class. A OpenGL-3 class GPU can not do OpenGL-4 (but a OpenGL-4 can do OpenGL-3 of course).

For all practical means there's nothing you need to download or to install to get working with OpenGL. This is different from DirectX where you need a special SDK. OpenGL has been included into the ABI (Application Binary Interface) of the major operating systems, including Windows, and hence the standard headers ship with compilers targeted at this system.

In your case you'll find the OpenGL base headers being preinstalled with the default installation of Visual-C++.

However newer versions of OpenGL require additional tokens and functions to be defined. That's where extension headers come into play. But since there's no change in the ABI, the actual functions do not come as part of a library but must be loaded at runtime using `wglGetProcAddress` for each function.

Since this is a tedious process there are OpenGL extension loader wrapper libraries, like GLEW (available at http://glew.sf.net) which package up the extension headers and some library code to do the whole loading thing with just a single command. Since there are things to consider like namespace pollution and interoperability with other means of extension loading, GLEW patches into the regular OpenGL headers with preprocessor macro definitions, so that all compilation units that include GLEW just use GLEW. This makes it look like GLEW replaces the regular headers and interface libraries, but in reality it just builds on and defers to them.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, now it all is starting to make more sense to me.